# Trying to find and import a txt file from desktop

Tags: google-apps-script

I am really only used to using VBA for scripting so this is a very new world for me. With that being said I am trying to write a script out that will be able to find a .txt file based on a user input and then import said file from my C: drive into a blanksheet in the workbook. Is this a capability that Apps script has?

Comment: If you perform the file upload from a dialog or web app with an html element <input  type = file.  This has a form that contains a file upload: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61449946/7215091

Comment: Google Apps Script is built around Javascript and many people that know javascript are familiar with web development so it's a natural thing for us to build interfaces with html, css and javascript.  And google makes it even easier to access the server with google.script.run

Comment: The "based on user input" bit suggests that the import is done interactively. What is stopping you from simply using **File > Import**?

Comment: Finding the file on your computer is  your computer is not a google apps script capability since it runs on Google Servers.

Comment: Cooper- thank you for the insight here I am trying to go down the html path you suggested. I understand the capability is not there for the exact solution I am looking for and am trying to redesign this system.

Comment: doubleunary- the reason that I am looking to automate this process is because the tasks after the import requires alot of data manipulation. I do understand that I will be able to write a script to do what I need post import. With how green I am to javascript and sheets I was unaware of its capabilities and wanted to see how complete I could make the macro.